# Why is find piping in non directories when the “-type d” test is used?

Tags: find, pipe, gnu-parallel

I have a directory

```
~/root/
|-- bar
|-- eggs
|-- foo
|-- hello.txt
|-- script.sh
`-- spam

4 directories, 2 files
```

Issuing `find . -type d` while in `~/root/` yields

```
.
./spam
./eggs
./bar
./foo
```

However, issuing `find . -type d | parallel "echo {}" ::: *` yields

```
bar
eggs
foo
hello.txt
script.sh
spam
```

Why are the nondirectories `hello.txt` and `script.sh` piped here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html), the `::: *` syntax uses the shell's expansion of `*` as an argument list instead of anything from `stdin`. So as written, your command ignores the result of `find` and passes all files in the current directory as arguments. If you leave off the `::: *`, it should work as intended.